# How do I collect chars into a string in C?

Tags: c, char, concatenation

I need to collect some chars into the buffer for my lexer, but I don't know how. I've read some answers on stackoverflow, but those are different cases. I have a while loop that reads next char and I want to put logic in it so it append new char to the buffer in memory.

```c
// init buffer with the first char 'h'
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
buffer[0] = 'h';
buffer[1] = '\0';

// go through input char by char
while(...)
{
   char c = read_next_char(); 
   buffer.append(c) // I whould do in JavaScript, but not in C :(
}
```

Comment: Beginning you need to allocated `x` number of bytes and read char each time and store it to buffer. You also need to take care of re-sizing the buffer using `realloc`.
In your case you are allocating a single byte `char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));` and access `buffer[1]` or any other index is UB

Comment: Are you trying to read a C type string char-by-char or just a raw char array?

Comment: Look at your own code for 5 seconds. Does the malloc seem correct given what you do with `buffer` afterwards? I'm assuming you think that C has a string class. It has not, and that string class which it doesn't have is not `char`.

Comment: Before to speak about your own lexers you must speak about what strings and chars are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a no standard function in C that can append a char to a string. You need to write the code from scratch.

Let's start here:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));  // This allocates memory for ONE char
buffer[0] = 'h';                      // So this is fine
buffer[1] = '\0';                     // but this is bad. It writes outside the allocated memory
```

Fix it by allocating memory for two chars

```
char *buffer = malloc(2);  // sizeof(char) is always 1 so no need for it
buffer[0] = 'h';
buffer[1] = '\0';
```

When you want to append a new character to the string, you also need to allocate memory for it. In other words, you need to increase the size of the memory that `buffer` is pointing to. For that you can use the function `realloc`.

```
size_t buffer_size = 2;
char *buffer = malloc(buffer_size );
buffer[0] = 'h';
buffer[1] = '\0';

while(...)
{
    char c = read_next_char(); 

    char* tmp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        // realloc failed ! Add error handling here
        ... error handling ...
    }
    buffer = tmp;
    buffer[buffer_size - 1] = c;  // Add the new char
    buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';     // Add the string termination
    ++buffer_size;                  // Update buffer size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are allocating a single byte `char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));` at the beginning and access buffer[1] or any other index is UB.

You can allocate a known number of bytes at beginning and use it until you see a point you need more buffer size.

something like this,

```
int buffersize = 100;
int index =0;
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*buffersize); //100bytes are allocated

if(!buffer)
    return;

buffer[index++] = 'h';
buffer[index++] = '\0';

// go through input char by char
while(...)
{
   char c = read_next_char(); 
   if(index == buffersize ){
      buffersize +=100;
       buffer= realloc(buffer, buffersize );
      //here buffer size is increased by 100
       if(!buffer) 
           return;
   }
   
   buffer[index++] = c ;
}
```

Note: You must free the `buffer` once the usage is over else it would lead to resource leak.

Answer (score 2):

You need simple to overwrite the null terminating character and add the new one.

```
char *append(char *buff, int ch)
{
    size_t len = strlen(buff);
    buff[len] = ch;
    buff[len+1] = 0;
    return buff;
}
```

The code assumes that `buff` is a valid pointer to long enough memory block to accommodate the new char and null terminating char. It has to contain a valid C string.

Comment: For longer strings this will become very inefficient. See this very good article: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is only the indication of the method. Of course, there are many ways of doing it more efficiently. But the **idea** is the same.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It depends where the chars are coming from... If it's some kind of IO stream (especially if it's stdin) it doesn't matter as IO is slow. In that case it's great to keep things simple like this.

Comment: An alternative implementation of this could be: `char *append(char *buff, int ch) { char str[2] = {ch, '\0'}; return strcat(buff, str); }`

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in java or javascipt there is no string type in C, you need to write your own.

This is a very simple example of how you could handle the building of strings in an efficient way.

It's pretty self explaining.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct DynamicString
{
  char* string;    // pointer to string
  int length;      // string length
  int capacity;    // capacity of the string buffer (= allocated size)
};

#define DS_CHUNKSIZE 100   // we increase the buffer size by DS_CHUNKSIZE
                           // change this as needed

// Initialize the structure
void InitDynamicString(struct DynamicString* ds)
{
  ds->capacity = DS_CHUNKSIZE + 1;
  ds->string = malloc(ds->capacity);
  ds->string[0] = 0;   // null terminator
  ds->length = 0;      // initial string length 0
};

// Increase the string buffer size if necessary
// (internal function)
void IncreaseSize(struct DynamicString* ds, int newsize)
{
  if (ds->length + newsize + 1 > ds->capacity)
  {
    ds->capacity = ds->length + newsize + DS_CHUNKSIZE + 1;
    ds->string = realloc(ds->string, ds->capacity); // reallocate a new larger buffer
  }
}

// append a single character
void AppendChar(struct DynamicString* ds, char ch)
{
  IncreaseSize(ds, sizeof(char)); // increase size by 1 if necessary
  ds->string[ds->length++] = ch;  // append char
  ds->string[ds->length] = 0;     // null terminator
}

// append a string
void AppendString(struct DynamicString* ds, const char *str)
{
  IncreaseSize(ds, strlen(str));  // increase by length of string if necessary
  strcat(ds->string, str);        // concatenate
  ds->length += strlen(str);      // update string length
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  struct DynamicString ds;

  InitDynamicString(&ds);   // initialize ds

  AppendChar(&ds, 'a');     // append chars
  AppendChar(&ds, 'b');
  AppendChar(&ds, 'c');

  AppendString(&ds, "DE");      // append strings
  AppendString(&ds, "xyz1234");

  printf("string = \"%s\"", ds.string);  // show result
}
```

You code could use it like this:

```
struct DynamicString buffer;
InitDynamicString(&buffer)

dAppendChar(&buffer, 'h');

while(...)
{
   char c = read_next_char(); 
   AppendChar(&buffer, c); // quite similar to  buffer.append(c)
}
```

Disclaimer:

- The code hasn't been thoroughly tested and there may be bugs.
- There is no error checking whatsoever. `malloc` and `realloc` may fail.
- Other useful functions such as `SetString(struct DynamicString *ds, const char *string)` need to be written.
- There is room for optimisation, especially the `strcat` could be handled differently, read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) for more information. I leave this as a (very simple) exercise to the reader.

Comment: Minor: `strcat` can be replaced with a `strcpy`

Comment: @4386427 yep, that's the 3rd point of the disclaimer

Answer (score 0):

The other answers can work but they are complex. I suggest a simpler solution. A string is an array of `char`'s where the last `char` of that string is a `'\0'`-Byte. There can be more `char`'s in the array after it but they are not part of the string.

The simpler solution is to create an array which is large enough for 98% of cases, use it to store the string and when the string gets too long you can exit with an error. Changing the buffer size when needed is a nice feature but when you are new to C you shouldn't start there.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
// init buffer with the first char 'h'
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
buffer[0] = 'h';
buffer[1] = '\0';

// go through input char by char Replace the ... with your condition of the while loop
for(size_t i=1;...;i++) //start at 1 so the 'h' is not overwritten
{
   if(i==BUFFER_SIZE-1) //-1 for the '\0'-Byte
   {
     fputs("Input too long, exit\n",stderr);
     exit(1);
   }
   //Are you sure you don't need error handling for read_next_char()?
   buffer[i] = read_next_char();
   buffer[i+1]='\0'; //End the string with a '\0'-Byte
}
```